# Icons in the tray do not work properly Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, icons

**Context**
I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 from an iso on my Asus X202E and everything was working fine so far. However I discovered that the icons from the tray (dropbox, wifi, keyboard, layout, battery and so on) are not working properly.

**Problem Description**
Most of the time when I click on them they show the menu I am expecting to see but in some cases they just do not respond at all. I then move my pointer and re-click and everything is working well. This is not a big deal but I do not understand the cause of that and I would like to fix it for a smoother use.

Note that not all the icons are not working. The three most right buttons are ok: (shutdown-system settings-...) icon, sound options and clock-calendar icons.

**Solutions tried**
I already ran `killall unity-panel-service` but that did not solve the problem.

As proposed by Angel Salinas Huerta, I enabled the proposed updates in the software center and upgraded the system, but the problem is still there.

After wandering for some times on this site and some *googling* I hpoe to find some answers from you!

Comment: Do you have problems clicking on anywhere else?

Comment: @wilf 
 
Not that I know so far. Everything else is working nicely plus the icons for the (shutdown-system settings-...) menu, the sound options and the clock-calendar option work well all the time, it is only battery, mails, keyboard, wifi, bluetooth and dropbox icons which are not working. I don't have other icons there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be refering to this bug, wich fizx was already released but probably hasn't made it to normal updates.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

You can however enable Proposed updates in Software Center>Edit>Sources and just update the mentioned packages or update the whole system.

Comment: After doing what you suggested, the problem was still there but disappeared so far after a reboot of the machine.